# React Native: How to test a async component snapshot with Jest/Testing-library?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to create a test for an **async** component in React Native. This component uses `useEffect` to fetch for data, sets it to a state variable and loads the screen accordingly. Once it is all loaded I'd like to compare it to a snapshot. The issue I am having is my test is synchronous, when I check the rendered snapshot it has my loading indicator.

How can I wait for it to load the data and then perform tests?

All the examples and tutorials I find are for sync components, involving simple tasks like checking a button for a specific title, this and the other. I've tried `waitFor` function but it times out before the data is fetched, apparently it has a 5 second limit. Or maybe I should mock a fetch (?) but my component doesn't take any props to inject the data into it.

To be honest I am very confused on how to approach this. I've never done any automated tests before.

Comment: Show the minimal code

Answer (score 0):

After much confusion in my head I figured it out.

In Jest, whenever you use an external source like an API call using fetch or axios, you have to mock it. This means that Jest will take any axios requests from your component or function and instead of calling the real axios it will call your mock axios **automatically**. This was the explanation that I was missing and the source of my confusion. The beauty of jest mocking is that you will always get the same data for your tests keeping results and assertions consistent.

There are many ways to mock Axios with Jest including libraries for this specific purpose like `jest-mock-axios` and `MSW` (Mock Service Worker) but I couldn't get them to work in my case.

I found a much easier way without the need of external libraries described in the following YouTube tutorial. This guy knows how to explain things and he has a newer video using MSW (link in the YouTube comments).

[YouTube: Mocking Axios in Jest + Testing Async Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Yrd4aZkse8&t=340s)

### Solution

This is the component to be tested, as you can see there is a axios request triggered by `useEffect` on mount.

`/screens/Home.tsx`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, memo } from "react";
import { FlatList, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import axios from "axios";
import Item from "../components/Item";
import AppConfig from "../AppConfig.json";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from "../components/Themed";
import Toast from "react-native-toast-message";

import { RootTabScreenProps } from "../types";

let _isMounted = false;

function Home({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<"Shop">) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    _isMounted = true;
    loadData();

    return () => {
      _isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  async function loadData(cb?: any) {
    try {
      axios.get(`${AppConfig.api}/products`).then((res) => {
        if (!_isMounted) return;

        if (res.status === 200) {
          const { data } = res;
          setItems(data);
        } else {
          setError(`Error ${res.status}: failed to load products`);
        }

        setLoading(false);
        setRefreshing(false);

        if (typeof cb === "function") cb();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      setRefreshing(false);
      setError("Failed to load products");
      // console.log(error);
    }
  }

  if (loading && !error) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerCenter}>
        <ActivityIndicator size={"large"} color="primary" />
      </View>
    );
  } else if (!loading && error) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.containerCenter}>
        <Text>{error}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Try again"
          onPress={() => {
            setLoading(true);
            setError("");
            loadData();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          columnWrapperStyle={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}
          data={items}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={({ item }: any) => {
            return (
              <Item
                item={item}
                onPress={() => navigation.push("Product", item)}
              />
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item: object, index: any) => index}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => {
            setRefreshing(true);
            loadData(() => {
              Toast.show({
                type: "success",
                text1: "Product list refreshed",
                position: "bottom",
              });
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  containerCenter: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: "80%",
  },
  textError: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
    maxWidth: 250,
  },
});

export default memo(Home);
```

**Step 1**

Create a folder at the root of your project called `__mocks__` (or wherever your source code is!) and create a file called `axios.js` containing the following object:

`/__mocks__/axios.js`

```
export default {
    get: jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
        headers: {},
        config: {},
        status: 200,
        statusText: "OK",
        data: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops",
                price: 109.95,
                description:
                    "Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday",
                category: "men's clothing",
                image: "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
                rating: { rate: 3.9, count: 120 },
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Mens Casual Premium Slim Fit T-Shirts ",
                price: 22.3,
                description:
                    "Slim-fitting style, contrast raglan long sleeve, three-button henley placket, light weight & soft fabric for breathable and comfortable wearing. And Solid stitched shirts with round neck made for durability and a great fit for casual fashion wear and diehard baseball fans. The Henley style round neckline includes a three-button placket.",
                category: "men's clothing",
                image:
                    "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71-3HjGNDUL._AC_SY879._SX._UX._SY._UY_.jpg",
                rating: { rate: 4.1, count: 259 },
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: "Mens Cotton Jacket",
                price: 55.99,
                description:
                    "great outerwear jackets for Spring/Autumn/Winter, suitable for many occasions, such as working, hiking, camping, mountain/rock climbing, cycling, traveling or other outdoors. Good gift choice for you or your family member. A warm hearted love to Father, husband or son in this thanksgiving or Christmas Day.",
                category: "men's clothing",
                image: "https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71li-ujtlUL._AC_UX679_.jpg",
                rating: { rate: 4.7, count: 500 },
            },
        ],
        })
    ),
};
```

Adjust the response from your `Promise.resolve(...)` to whatever you expect your real API to return. Also, make sure you are mocking the function by using `jest.fn()` otherwise this will not work.

You can also add different properties to you mocked axios object like post, update, put or whatever type of request you need to mock.

**Step 2**

In the root of your source code again, create a folder called `__tests__` and inside of it create a folder called `screens`. Then create your test file, to keep things consistent I named mine `Home.test.js`.

`/__tests__/screens/Home.test.js`

```
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import axios from "axios";
import { act } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import Home from "../../screens/Home";

// Important:
// By calling this, jest will know not to use the real axios and will load it
// from your __mocks__ folder.
jest.mock("axios");

describe("<Home />", () => {
let wrapper;

it("renders items", async () => {
    await act(async () => {
    // This is where the magic happens, when you render your Home component and useEffect
    // goes to perform your axios request jest will automatically call your __mocks__/axios instead
    wrapper = await renderer.create(<Home />);
    });

    await expect(wrapper.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it("renders error", async () => {
    await act(async () => {
    // You can also override your __mocks__/axios by doing the following and simulate a different
    // response from your mocking axios
    await axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
        Promise.resolve({
        status: 400,
        statusText: "400",
        headers: {},
        config: {},
        })
    );

    wrapper = await renderer.create(<Home />);
    });

    await expect(wrapper.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
});
```

Now when you run `npm run test` your Home component will receive the data from your `__mocks__/axios` and render it as expected and you can perform all sorts of tests on it.

This is actually really cool!